# Applying some mathematical operation to a signal in SIMULINK

Tags: simulink

Good day,

I need some help in some mathematical operations in SIMULINK. I have a signal coming from a block. The signal always has the first few entries 
as `9999`. Then, the next entry is a value between `0` and `200`, say: `100`. After that, all other remaining entries are back to `9999`. This is always the nature of signal, except that the value: `100` may change its value or location in different simulations but it always has one or more values of `9999` before it, and all other entries after it are also `9999`.

This is an example of the signal coming from a block:

```
S=[9999 75 9999 9999 9999]
```

Another example:

```
S=[9999 9999 9999 100 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999]
```

I want to pass this signal to another block or MATLAB Function in SIMULINK so that once the value (`75` in the first example or `100` in the second example) is read, it will stay forever till the end of simulations.

Therefore, the desired output for the first example is:

```
Y=[9999 75 75 75 75]
```

And for the second example is:

```
Y=[9999 9999 9999 100 100 100 100 100 100]
```

So all remaining `9999`’s are replaced by that value.

I tried to use a MATLAB Function with some `if-else` statements. Also, I tried using blocks of delay and comparisons, but I wasn’t able to get the desired output.

Is there a solution to that either using MATLAB Function or using some SIMULINK blocks ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following, with initializing `Memory` block with `9999`

[image]

and the result,

[image]

zoomed results,

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Hazem. Perfect. You know this took around 6 hours for me trying finding the solution. You gave the solution in minutes :). Thanks so much. I appreciate your help :)